# Query mongo database for field value without returning contents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm running a small node server that checks a mongo DB if a product exists. It then returns the product information to a mobile app. The products often have multiple images associated with them, which can be slow for the mobile app to download, and not always necessary. What I want to do is check the database if the product has images in the "images" array, and if so just return a boolean, not the images themselves. The user will then decide to make another GET request for just the images, based on whether or not that boolean is true.

Code from server:

```
router.route('/products/:sku')
.get(function (req, res) {
    var query = Product.find({sku: req.params.sku}, {
        name: true,
        sku: true,
        storeName: true,
        timeScanned: true,
        scannedBy: true,
        activity: true,
        activityId: true,
        images: true
    });
    query.exec(function (err, product) {
        if (product.images.length > 0) {
            product.images = true;
        } else {
            product.images = false;
        }
        if (err) return (err);
        if (product[0]) {
            res.json({
                message: 'Product in Database!',
                product: product[0]
            });
```

I get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' when I query for a product that I know contains two images in the "images" array. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** The error was actually fairly simple. For some reason, mongo returns its results in an array, so to check the length of "images" I had to check product **[0]**.images.length *not* product.images.length

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB [**aggregation framework**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/aggregation/) to get the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array, and then decide what to do. So consider this aggregation query:

```
Product.aggregate([{'$match': {'sku': req.params.sku}}, {'$project': {
        name: true,
        sku: true,
        storeName: true,
        timeScanned: true,
        scannedBy: true,
        activity: true,
        activityId: true,
        hasImages: {'$size': '$images'}
    }}],
    function (err, product) {
        if (product.images.length > 0) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
)
```

This will get you a cursor, containing the documents that matched your query, with one difference, that it will not contain your `images` field, but rather `imagesSize` field which will indicate the number of items in the `images` array.

Comment: That does seem cleaner than what I'm doing, and offers more information than what I tried. However, I'm getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'readPreference' of undefined" when I try to run that code. Ideas?

Comment: which part? the aggregate one?

Comment: I'm not sure... where does the readPreference command come from?

Comment: `readPreference` is not a command, it is an option for a `read` request, which tells, where the data should be read from, e.g. `primaryPreferred`, `secondaryOnly`. Can you tell on which line the error is occurring?